# usage of case in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to retrieve records from customer table with customername,city

```
custname|city
Anand|London
Paul|Rome
    .
    .
    .
```

however when retriving,if the city is London then Brussels should be displayed in its place and else original city name is to be displayed.
I have tried thee following query'

```
select custname,case city when 'London' then 'Brussels' end from customer;
```

and

```
select custname,deocde(city,'London','Brussels') from customer;
```

Both are giving the result as:

```
custname|city
Anand|Brussels
Pau|
```

Other cities are not being displayed.How to write this query correctly.Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ELSE`:

```
select custname, case  
                    when city = 'London' then 'Brussels' 
                    else city 
                 end as city
from customer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `else` clause:

```
select custname,
       (case city when 'London' then 'Brussels'
                  else city
        end) as city
from customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode has an "else" clause.  The usual format is `DECODE(column, search1, replace1[, search2, replace2][, default])`

For example: `DECODE(city, 'London', 'Brussels', city)`

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm